# iOS Flip UIView without shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I use `transitionFromView` and `.TransitionFlipFromLeft` to replace a view to another view.
Then I want to flip view without shadow above the views.

```
UIView.transitionFromView(
 self.postListView,
 toView:     self.userListView,
 duration:   0.8,
 options:    .TransitionFlipFromLeft,
 completion: nil
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:YES];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:SecondViewController animated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This is how to perform a card flipping animation in swift 3:

UIView.transition(from: frontImageView,
to: backImageView,
duration: 0.65,
options: .transitionFlipFromRight,
completion: nil)